# Why is rendering of this pu markup weird?

Tags: support, mhchem

`$\pu{1.08378‬0 mol}$` renders as $\pu{1.08378‬0 mol}$

I think mhchem renders \pu.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because you have a [tiny, invisible character](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202c/index.htm) between the 8 and the 0. Move your arrow keys back and forth inside the text; you'll find you need one extra key to traverse the gap between 8 and 0.

https://www.babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/whatisit.html says:

```
U+0024 : DOLLAR SIGN {milréis, escudo}
U+005C : REVERSE SOLIDUS {backslash}
U+0070 : LATIN SMALL LETTER P
U+0075 : LATIN SMALL LETTER U
U+007B : LEFT CURLY BRACKET {left brace}
U+0031 : DIGIT ONE
U+002E : FULL STOP {period, dot, decimal point}
U+0030 : DIGIT ZERO
U+0038 : DIGIT EIGHT
U+0033 : DIGIT THREE
U+0037 : DIGIT SEVEN
U+0038 : DIGIT EIGHT
U+202C : POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING [PDF]
U+0030 : DIGIT ZERO
U+0020 : SPACE [SP]
U+006D : LATIN SMALL LETTER M
U+006F : LATIN SMALL LETTER O
U+006C : LATIN SMALL LETTER L
U+007D : RIGHT CURLY BRACKET {right brace}
U+0024 : DOLLAR SIGN {milréis, escudo}
```

There is a `U+202C` between `8` and `0`.

This special character is used to mark the [end of a right-to-left script part in a left-to-right text (or vice versa)](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/#Bidi_Class_Values).

Comment: Wow!! You earn the Sherlock Holmes badge for figuring that out!

Comment: I like the first edition with python and bash more:( Another question is how @MaxW got the symbol there: was it an intentional attempt to break mhchem or was it just copy-pasted from the third-party source?

Comment: @andselisk - LOL, you give me too much credit. I am not nearly that devious. // I really have no idea how to reproduce the problem, but I think that it might be related to copy and paste from the MS calculator of Windows 10.

Comment: @MaxW Ah, I see. I tried to copy a number from the Windows 10 system calculator by dragging the mouse slightly across the interface and I also got `U+202C : POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING [PDF]` at the end. That's one of the reasons I use web browser's console instead: `F12` → *Console*, put this on the sidebar and you got a nice built-in calculator with all JS functions at hand:)

Comment: @andselisk, I like this better. I didn't even bother to print the Unicode code points...

Comment: @Max IIRC copying from a PDF or similar word processing formats can cause the same issue.